# impossible unexpected '{' parse error

Tags: php, parse-error

I'm not sure how many times I can read posts about or count braces, brackets and semicolons after they all line up.  This has been racking me for hours.  Any insight would be appreciated.

This program has been working on and off most of the day.  When I've posted it and it worked I'd see details that need attention.  Sometimes making adjustments to it crashes it, like this.

The text content is irrelevant because after taking it out the problem is still there.
Says it's line 98.

Is the code indented properly?  I tried.

```
ini_set ('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting (E_ALL | E_STRICT);

require ('head_metas.htm');
require ('head_menus.htm');

//bid_handler.php

// get items
$title = trim($_POST['title']);
$img = trim($_POST['img']);
$medium = trim($_POST['medium']);
$size = trim($_POST['size']);
$date = trim($_POST['date']);
$value = trim($_POST['value']);

// visitor info
$visitorF = trim($_POST['visitorF']);
$visitorL = trim($_POST['visitorL']);
$phone = trim($_POST['phone']);
$email1 = trim($_POST['email1']);
$email2 = trim($_POST['email2']);
$validation1 = filter_var($email1, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$validation2 = filter_var($email2, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

$bid_value = trim($_POST['bid_value']);

// confirmation mails
$headers = '...';
$to = 'my@email.com, $email1';
$subject = '...';
$message = $visitorF . $visitorL . ' has offered ' . $bid_value . ' for ' . $title . '.\n\nContact information:\nPnone: ' . $phone . '\nemail address: ' . $email1;

$okay = TRUE;
// welcome + image
if ($okay == TRUE)
{
    print "
        <p>
         Luring text and a captivating image
             <br />
             All \" quotes \" are meticulously struck
        </p>
          ";
    $okay = TRUE;
}



// inaccessible entries
if ( 
    (empty($visitorF)) || 
    (empty($visitorL)) || 
    (empty($email1)) || 
    (empty($email2)) || 
    ($email1 != $email2) ||
    ($validation1 == NULL) || 
    ($validation2 == NULL) 
    ) 
{
    print " 
        There were errors.
        ";
    $okay = FALSE;
}

    // everything looks great
    elseif ( 
        ($okay == TRUE) &&
        (is_numeric($bid_value)) && 
        ($bid_value >= $value) &&
        (isset($visitorF)) && 
        (isset($visitorL)) && 
        (isset($email1)) && 
        (isset($email2)) && 
        ($email1 == $email2) &&
        ($validation1 == TRUE) &&
        ($validation2 == TRUE) 
        ) 
    {
        print "
            <p>
              Thank you, your information is as follows:
              <br />
              Info... prints the variables in a stylish fashion
             </p> ";
             $okay = FALSE;
    }

        else ( 
            ($bid_value < $value) || 
            (empty($bid_value)) 
            )
        {
            print "
                <p>
                 However, your bid has not met the minimum reserve for this piece.
                <br />
                 Please enter a numeric value and try again.
                </p>
                 ";
            $okay = FALSE;
        }


require ('footer.html');
?>
```

Comment: "Is the code indented properly?" Indentation is only to make the code easier to read. You have a condition on the `else`, which you cannot have.

Comment: change that `else` to `elseif`

Answer (score 6):

Not sure, but I think the problem is here:

```
 else ( 
        ($bid_value < $value) || 
        (empty($bid_value)) 
        )
```

You can't have a `(condition)` after the `else` keyword.

Comment: Wouldnt `elseif() {}` be a better option?

Comment: Thanks Richard.  It rocks now.

Comment: @midithru - FYI You can [accept one of these answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (to clearly indicate which one helped you the most) using the [checkmark to the left of the answers](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png).

Answer (score 3):

**Error In**

```
    else ( 
        ($bid_value < $value) || 
        (empty($bid_value)) 
        )
```

You can't use condition in **else** replace it with **else if** or **remove condition**

Answer (score 2):

```
  else ( 
        ($bid_value < $value) || 
        (empty($bid_value)) 
        )
    {
```

Here is the error You cannot use condition in `else` statement 
Basic structure of `if-else` statemtent is

```
if(condition){
     //condition is true
}else{
     //condition is false
}
```

if you want to use more condition than use `elseif`

```
if(condition){
//condition is true
}elseif(condition){
//condition is false
}else{
}
```

You are using a single `elseif` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Look here:

```
    else ( 
        ($bid_value < $value) || 
        (empty($bid_value)) 
        )
    {
```

Now let's minify it a little:

```
else (($bid_value < $value) || (empty($bid_value))) {
```

Then you see the problem very obviously. You do not simply have a condition after the `else` statement. The else statement's design in PHP (see the [PHP.net documentation for the else control structure](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.else.php)) makes it clean up all the possible cases for an `if` statement. That makes it not able to accept any conditions, as anything which is not accepted by the other conditions gets into the `else` statement.